# Sphinx apidoc not automated enough

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm working in a large repo with ~100 individual folders, each with 20-30 sub-folders, each of which contain their own .py folders. Currently I have to create the .rst file for each file using the sphinx-apidoc command, then add the path to the conf.py file then add the .rst file to the index.rst file. Is there anyway of automating this so that all of this is done with just a couple of commands.

Comment: What command are you using for [`sphinx-apidoc`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html)? You shouldn't have to do anything manual, if you use the correct options and your directories have `__init__.py` files inside to make them Python modules.

Comment: I'm doing sphinx-apidoc - o source/../folder/subfolder. My problem is that the .rst files don't get created recursively and I have to add these paths to my conf.py file

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py`s in your folders making them Python modules and therefore discoverable by `sphinx-apidoc`? Did you try `-a module_path`, `--separate`, or `--implicit-namespaces` to see what they do?

Comment: i got it working with the __init__.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`sphinx-autodoc`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html) extension states that it will document Python packages. [Python packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) in turn require that their files (modules) be contained within a directory, and that each directory contain a file with the name of `__init__.py`.

After you have properly set up your files and directories, then Sphinx can import them and run `sphinx-autodoc` as expected.